# website to publish article on high-performance cluster computing?

Tags: publishing, technical-writing

I am writing a tutorial-type article on high-performance cluster computing. It is aimed at researchers and grad students who want to use clusters to answer scientific questions, especially in the life sciences. I may want to re-use text from this article for future, expanded versions - long-term goal is a series of articles or even a book.

I have put a lot of work and time into the article already, and I simply do not want to publish it on some random blog. I am looking for a suitable website to publish the article. I do not expect financial renumeration, but I want a website where I have a lot of audience and of course the right audience.

A website which seemed very suited at first is IBM developerWorks: the article would get a lot of exposition, many readers, and I like how the website is designed and that there is a limited form of peer-review. But, I find the publishing policy and rules of IBM developerWorks ridiculous and just downright offensive. Anything you publish there is considered "work for hire" which means you give all rights over to IBM, and you can not re-use your own stuff in any other form elsewhere etc. So developerWorks is out of the question.

There are scientific journals of course, but this is also not the right forum for my article, because my article deals with very practical aspects of scientific cluster programming and computing, but so much with the science itself.

Do you know of a site very similar to IBM dveloperWorks in scope and audience, but with a more reasonable policy? Or, do you have any recommendation for a *good* (i.e., not just some random blog) site where I could publish my article? Any suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: We're [discussing this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4599186#4599186), would you like to join in?

Comment: Define "random blog". If it's *your* blog, then what is "random" about it?

Comment: @JohnSmither - I think what's meant here is a blog that's not targeting the appropriate audience?

Comment: @John Smithers: I don't want to define random blog. What I meant is, I was wondering if s/o can recommend a website similar to IBM developerWorks, but not actually developerWorks because of their copyright rules and regulations, which are inacceptible. "Random blog": some website where I can publish but where no-one who cares about cluster computing will ever find  my article. I personally do not have a blog, and I don't want to make a blog either. I am looking for a tech website with 1000s of users. Like I said, similar to developerWorks.

Comment: Why can't you publish it in a journal?  You want some famous website to give you a chance, and let you keep the rights, but why should they? Their blog, their rules. Why not your own blog? That is a good way to build credibility, which is needed if you want to sell non-fiction.

Answer (score 1):

If your article centers on a particular cluster implementation, then finding the right audience depends a lot on the *kind* of clustering you are using, since a lot of websites are going to center around a particular platform or vendor.  For generic high-performance computing (HPC), you could start with a site like "[HPC Wire](http://www.hpcwire.com/)."  If your article is a "How To" article on building a cluster with open source software, I would suggest something like "[HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/)."  Since you are orienting toward "researchers and grad students who want to use clusters to answer scientific questions," though, it may be best to **target a specific academic community and submit your article for publication in their literature.**